# Convert alpha beta gamma (deviceorientation event) to portrait or landscape orientation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, orientation

What's the best way to do this? I'm using window.addEventListener("deviceorientation" ....)

I can't use some of the more popular methods, because if the user clicks lock screen on their phone, popular methods like using "resize" won't work. 
I need to know whether the user is in portrait or landscape mode. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but I have an idea. Convert to a rotation matrix, then swap x and y axis, then you have a rotation matrix for landscape mode. Can convert the new rotation matrix to alpha beta gamma if needed.